# Users unable to view order history

Tags: ubercart

I have drupal 6 with ubercart
When a user clicks on View order history, it takes them to a please register or login page.
Admin can see order history just fine.

I've checked the options for 
Allow customers to view order invoices from their order history in Order settings and it's set to true.
I've checked permissions and its set to allow authorized and even anonymous users to view own orders.
Yet they keep getting this strange redirect to register or login.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions where else to check for the problem.
I haven't been able to find the solutions yet.

Thanks!!

UPDATE:
I just noticed what when the Admin account tries to look at another users order history
mysite.com/user/105718/orders
even admin gets please login or register.
I've triple checked permissions and its set for admin to have access to everything and for users to view their own order history. Still not working.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding permissions? https://drupal.org/node/147961

Comment: Yeah, I've ran the rebuild permissions in the
admin/content/node-settings section, didn't have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the view permissions?  They override drupal core permissions.

Also, is there an order content type, or entity type?  You have to grant anon and auth users access to view their own order content type in drupal core permissions.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, apparently there used to be a order_history view or something, but it was no longer there.
So I created a new order_history view and assigned it permissions, now the order history tab on users works fine.